# how to select the first row with minimum date for each unique value and specific condition

Tags: mysql

i have the following table

table 1

```
------------------------------------------
| animal_id | animal_name | animal_type |
------------------------------------------
|     1     | kay         | cat         |
|     2     | sandy       | dog         |
------------------------------------------
```

table 2

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| vaccine_id | animal_id  | vaccine_name | vaccine_status | vaccine_date |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 1          | rabies       | done           | 2015-09-09   |
| 2          | 1          | chlamydiasis | undone         | 2015-09-15   |
| 3          | 1          | parasite     | undone         | 2015-10-20   |
| 4          | 2          | parasytosis  | undone         | 2015-11-10   |
| 5          | 2          | rabies       | undone         | 2015-11-05   |
```

expected result:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | animal_id  | animal_name | animal_type | vacccine_id  | vaccine_name | vaccine_status  |  vaccine_date  |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 1          | kay         | cat         | 2            | chlamydiasis | undone          | 2015-09-15     | 
    | 2          | sandy       | dog         | 5            | rabies       | undone          | 2015-11-05     |
```

the result will show all the first row of each unique value between two tables with the most recent vaccine_date and the condition where the vaccine_status is undone. I'm using SQL by the way

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for [samples](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves. What [work](https://mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) have you already done?

Comment: well, i already tried `SELECT tbl1.animal_id, tbl1.animal_name, table1.animal_type, tbl2.vaccine_id, tbl2.vaccine_name, tbl2.vaccine_status, min(tbl2.vaccine_date) as vaccine_date FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.anima_id = tbl2.animal_id WHERE vaccine_status = "undone" GROUP BY tbl1.animal_name`

but the result only occured on vaccine_date, the rest of table 2 still only show the first row
@outis

Comment: most recent Vaccine date for animal 1 looks like 2015-10-20 and for Animal 2 2015-11-10. But your expected results says something else. Do you mean most older? Or I am missing something?.

Comment: Please add updates by editing the question rather than as comments. SO is a Q&A site, rather than a forum. Also, the desired results don't match the stated conditions, as vaccine 3 is the most recent "undone" vaccine for animal 1, not vaccine 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex queries you often need to manipulate the data with something like PHP. For example, using 2 queries on the data you provided:

```
<?php
    $link=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
    // Start with the list of animals
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM animals";
    $res = $link->query($sql);
    for($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_rows($res); ++$i){
        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $animal_id = $row1['animal_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vaccines WHERE animal_id = $animal_id AND vaccine_status = 'undone' ORDER BY vaccine_date ASC LIMIT 1";
        $res2 = $link->query($sql);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2);
        $arr[$animal_id] = array();
        array_push($arr[$animal_id], $row1['animal_name'], $row1['animal_type'], $row2['vaccine_id'], $row2['vaccine_name'], $row2['vaccine_status'], $row2['vaccine_date']);
    }

    echo "RESULT:";
    echo "<table border=1><tr><th>animal_id</th><th>animal_name</th><th>animal_type</th><th>vaccine_id</th><th>vaccine_name</th><th>vaccine_status</th><th>vaccine_date</th></tr>";
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".implode("</td><td>", $val)."</td></tr><br>";
    }
?>
```

...produces the following output:

[image: output from code]

Comment: a little complicated but neat! do you know how to generate it to json?

Comment: PHP has a handy function that converts any array to into json format. json_encode($array)

Comment: can you give me an example based on the code above? i tried it but the result isn't what i expecting

Comment: If you remove the result section and replace it with `echo json_encode($arr);` it will print the array in json format. Note that the element names will be the animal id's.

Comment: right, i got it! now how to put the value name, like the animal_id, animal_name, etc exactly into it?

Comment: This ought to do it.. [code on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/6vlI2g4M). Hope that helps.

Comment: nice! but it doesn't generate the array bracket in the beginning and the end, and comma for every new result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97807/discussion-between-cantelope-and-lia-dianti).

Comment: Data should never be interpolated directly into statements. Instead, use prepared statements, which are both safer and faster. Also, PHP isn't necessary here. The desired results can be achieved entirely with SQL.